# I have to find the period of all numbers in an given array, like there are many solutions but size of the array is 10^5

Tags: c++, implementation

Eg. The given array:[1,2,1,3,1,2,1,5]
should return-`1 -> 2
2 -> 4
3 -> 0
5 -> 0`

There is a solution I can think of but it is of O(n^2).
Suggest something better.

Comment: This is not a code writing website. What did you try?

Comment: Hash map that stores the last occurence of a value?

Comment: Also, what is a period?

Comment: @d4rk4ng31 in the given array 1 is repeated after every two terms, so its period is 2,
same with 2(repeated after 4 terms)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Transform in one linear scan your array into a hashmap of arrays indexed by value, containing the indices where that value was found. For your example this would be:

```
{
  1: [0, 2, 4, 6],
  2: [1, 5],
  3: [3],
  5: [7],
}
```

Then for each entry `l` in the hashmap output `0` if `len(l) <= 1`, and otherwise output `l[1] - l[0]`. If you also have to check that the period is consistent, check that `l[i] - l[i-1] == l[1] - l[0]` for all `i >= 2`.